# Using boxed with newline in it

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, line-breaking, boxes

I am new to LaTeX, cant figure out this issue. I want a box around the following equation.

```
\begin{equation}
A  State  S_{t}   is  Markov if and only  if  : \newline
P [ S_{t+1}  |  S_{t} ] = P [  S_{t+1}   |  S_{1}.......S_{t} ]
\end{equation}
```

The `\newline` has no effect.
Some solutions say use `boxed`, `fbox` etc. but then I cannot use newline inside it gives me an error. If I use fbox the frame is too big, I just need a nice looking frame (like what boxed gives you), but I also want to use `\newline` in it.

Edit : I could not achieve exactly what the title says but I got what I wanted using the following lines.

```
\newcommand*\widebox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widebox]{align}
\nonumber\\
A \ State \ S_{t} \  is \ Markov \ if \ and \ only \ if \ :\\
P\ [\ S_{t+1}\  |\  S_{t}\ ] = P [ \ S_{t+1} \  | \  S_{1}.......S_{t} \ 
]\nonumber\\ \nonumber
\end{empheq}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Where do you have use a new line?

Comment: `\newline` does not do anything. I want a newline after the text.

Comment: `\text{A State $S_{t}$ is Markov if and only if:}` is probably what you want.